# How to know if addition of factorials changes the amount of trailing zeroes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, decimal-expansion

In this specific puzzle, it is $603!+604!+605!$.

If it was $603!*604!*605!$ instead, I would simply count all the occurrences of multiples of 5, 25 and 125, which would be $148$ for $603!$ and $604!$, and $149$ for $605!$, and add them together.

Yet in this puzzle the factorials are added together, so it could be either 148 zeroes—if the 149th zero of 605! gets overwritten—or more, if the digits which are not zero add up nicely, like in the solution, which says it's 150 zeroes at the end.

How can I determine if that will happen?

Comment: Hint: Write it as $603!(1+604+605\cdot604)$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Forgot about that one! But what to do when the gaps are bigger?

Comment: It should be okay, if the gaps are bigger you should only need to consider the smallest factorial.  You can only possibly have things canceling to give extra zeros when the gaps are small (you need two with the same number of zeroes to cancel out and get an extra zero).  For example, $603!+610!+611! = 603!(1+ \mbox{stuff that ends in at least one zero})$, so you only have as many trailing zeroes as come from the $603!$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Ah, of course... I should go to sleep—thanks though!